# MySQL JPA deleting multiple records from different tables

Tags: mysql, jpa

There are two tables:

```
        User table `user`
        +----+----------------------------+-------------+
        | id | date_created_user          | email       |
        +----+----------------------------+-------------+
        |  7 | 2023-02-23 13:23:09.085897 | www@www.www |
        | 16 | 2023-02-25 14:23:31.691560 | qqq@qqq.qqq |
        | 17 | 2023-02-25 14:24:02.089010 | aaa@aaa.aaa |
        | 18 | 2023-02-25 14:24:24.708500 | xxx@xxx.xxx |
        | 19 | 2023-02-25 14:25:19.253770 | ooo@ooo.ooo |
        +----+----------------------------+-------------+


        Deletion table `deletion`
        +----+----------------+----------------------------+---------+
        | id | active         | date                       | user_id |
        +----+----------------+----------------------------+---------+
        | 10 | false          | 2023-02-25 14:23:31.691560 |      16 |
        | 11 | false          | 2023-02-25 14:24:02.089010 |      17 |
        | 12 | true           | 2023-02-25 14:24:24.708500 |      18 |
        | 13 | true           | 2023-02-25 14:25:19.253770 |      19 |
        +----+----------------+----------------------------+---------+




        Relationship table `user_role`
        +---------+---------------+
        | user_id | role_id       |
        +---------+---------------+
        |       7 |            1  |
        |      16 |            2  |
        |      17 |            2  |
        |      18 |            2  |
        |      19 |            2  |
        +---------+---------------+



    DESCRIBE User `user`
    +-------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field                   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +-------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id                      | bigint      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | email                   | varchar(58) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
    | enabled                 | bit(1)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | password                | varchar(65) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | token                   | varchar(45) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
    +-------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+



    DESCRIBE Deletion `deletion`
    +--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field              | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id                 | bigint      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | active             | bit(1)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | date               | datetime(6) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | user_id            | bigint      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
    +--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


    DESCRIBE  `user_role`
    +---------------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field         | Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +---------------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | user_id       | bigint | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
    | role_id       | bigint | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
    +---------------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

It is necessary to delete certain records from these tables.

The condition is the following:

If in the **`Deletion`** `table`, the **`active`** field contains the value **`false`** and more than 24 hours have passed in the **`date`** field, then you need to delete this record and delete the record from the **`User`** `table`.

The **`user_id`** key in the **`Deletion`** `table`.

And also, there is a table of relations **`user_role`**. This is a table of the user and his role. It will not be possible to delete a user if there is a relationship. Therefore, it is also necessary to remove this relation.

**My repository**

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Repository
    public interface DeletionRepository extends JpaRepository<Deletion, Long> {



        @Transactional
        @Modifying
        @Query("DELETE FROM Deletion as a WHERE a.active = false AND a.date <= :date")
        void deleteDeletionByActiveAndDate(@Param("date") String date);


    }
```

Comment: How to delete a record from the User table and from the Deletion table?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you need to do some datetime manipulations in your delete query, which tend to be highly database specific, I suggest using the following native MySQL query:

```sql
DELETE
FROM User u
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Deletion d
    WHERE d.user_id = u.id AND
          d.active = false AND
          d.date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
);
```

If you also want to delete the record from the `Deleted` table, then setup a cascading foreign key on `user_id`, such that deleting the parent record from the `User` table will also delete the dependent record.

If you *can't* setup cascading deletion, on MySQL you could also use the following delete join:

```sql
DELETE u, d
FROM User u
INNER JOIN Deleted d
    ON d.user_id = u.id
WHERE d.active = false AND
      d.date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Comment: I have addressed this.  Setup a cascading delete from `User` to `Deleted` such that deleting a user's record in the former table will automatically delete the dependent record(s) in the latter table.

Comment: I understood what you mean. I'll try now.

Comment: I made a mistake when creating this question. I didn't mention the relationship table. I edited the question. There you need to additionally remove the entry from the relationship table.

Answer (score 0):

*NOTE: I wrote this answer partially with the assistance of GitHub Copilot.*

---

TL;DR: Use an appropriate [`CascadeType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html) such as `REMOVE` or `ALL` on your `Deletion` entity.

---

If you define the `User` and `Deletion` entities as follows:

```java
package org.behrang.stackoverflow.q75563217.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private Date createdAt;

    private String email;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Deletion> deletions = new ArrayList<>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public List<Deletion> getDeletions() {
        return deletions;
    }

    public void setDeletions(List<Deletion> deletions) {
        this.deletions = deletions;
    }

    public void addDeletion(Deletion deletion) {
        this.deletions.add(deletion);
    }
}

package org.behrang.stackoverflow.q75563217.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Deletions")
public class Deletion {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private boolean active;

    private Date date;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

And use the following `persistence.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
    <persistence-unit name="default">
        <class>org.behrang.stackoverflow.q75563217.entity.User</class>
        <class>org.behrang.stackoverflow.q75563217.entity.Deletion</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:32773/example"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And use this schema (generated by Hibernate automatically):

```sql
create table if not exists Deletions_SEQ
(
    next_val bigint null
);

create table if not exists Users
(
    id        int          not null primary key,
    createdAt datetime(6)  null,
    email     varchar(255) null
);

create table if not exists Deletions
(
    id      bigint      not null primary key,
    active  bit         not null,
    date    datetime(6) null,
    user_id int         null,
    constraint FK2bq97txm7h2eirrkbv84xpv2y foreign key (user_id) references Users (id)
);

create table if not exists Users_Deletions
(
    User_id      int    not null,
    deletions_id bigint not null,
    constraint UK_jhg9je4j0jwu07wpjw2yvm9ve unique (deletions_id),
    constraint FK98pxufvij990xbgyihq7lxn2a foreign key (User_id) references Users (id),
    constraint FKg1q9bnqdsn40gecsagv32b16q foreign key (deletions_id) references Deletions (id)
);

create table if not exists Users_SEQ
(
    next_val bigint null
);
```

Then this demo code shows how the cascading effect works:

```java
package org.behrang.stackoverflow.q75563217;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import jakarta.persistence.Persistence;
import org.behrang.stackoverflow.q75563217.entity.Deletion;
import org.behrang.stackoverflow.q75563217.entity.User;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");
        EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction tx = entityManager.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();

        Instant i1 = Instant.now().minus(Duration.ofHours(25));
        User u1 = new User();
        u1.setEmail("1@example.com");
        u1.setCreatedAt(Date.from(i1));

        Deletion d01 = new Deletion();
        d01.setDate(Date.from(Instant.now()));
        d01.setUser(u1);
        u1.addDeletion(d01);

        entityManager.persist(u1);

        tx.commit();
        entityManager.close();

        entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
        tx = entityManager.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();

        Deletion d11 = entityManager.find(Deletion.class, 1L);
        entityManager.remove(d11);

        tx.commit();
        entityManager.close();

        factory.close();
    }
}
```

Demo video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCZcJdi9wf8.

Sample code: https://github.com/behrangsa/so-75563217

For the age comparison, you can add the date/time logic to your JPQL query.

Comment: The logic in your delete query is wrong.  The requirement was: `and more than 24 hours have passed in the date field, then you need to delete this record`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The OP seems to be calculating this 24 hours in Java land and passing it to the JPQL query.

Comment: Your GitHub Copilot failed.

Comment: @Behrang - @Query("DELETE FROM Deletion d WHERE d.active = false AND d.date < :date")  - delete record from "Deletion table" but does not delete the user.

Comment: @MaksManagement How are you creating your tables? Can you add the output of `DESCRIBE Users` and `DESCRIBE Deletions` to your question?

Comment: @Maks Management - I made a mistake when creating this question.
I didn't mention the relationship table. I edited the question. There you need to additionally remove the entry from the relationship table.

Comment: What about timezone issues?  Could that be a problem when binding the current datetime minus one day?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I had put the CASCADE DELETE on the wrong side of the relationship when creating the tables.

Comment: The updated answer is working for me.